# bash, compare the output of a command

Tags: bash, comparison, arguments

I am trying to do something like this:

```
  if [ $(wc -l $f) -lt 2 ]
```

where $f is a file. When I run this, I get the error message:

```
  [: too many arguments
```

Does anybody know how to fix this line in my command?

The full script is:

```
for f in *.csv
do
  if [ $(wc -l $f) -lt 2 ]
      then
      echo $f
      fi
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

at least in my case `wc -l filename` does output `32 filename` being 32 the number of lines. so you must strip of the filename after the line count. 
You could change your code from

```
if [ $(wc -l $f) -lt 2 ]
```

to

```
if [ $(wc -l $f | cut -f1 -d' ') -lt 2 ]
```

or

```
if [ $(wc -l < $f) -lt 2 ]
```

If does not solve your problem please add the output of `wc -l filename` to your question or as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
  if (( $(wc -l < "$f") < 2 ))
```

or if you want to keep your syntax :

```
  if [ $(wc -l < "$f") -lt 2 ]
```

### Note

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably

```
if [ `cat $f | wc -l` -lt 2 ]
```

instead of

```
if [ $(wc -l $f) -lt 2 ]
```

Comment: No, this does not work, it has the same error msg when I run this command.

Comment: @user788171 Edited the answer. Check now